Prevent Chrome location reload warning banner
When changing site location permissions in Chrome, this banner slides into view prompting you to reload the page:

However, with the Permissions API, it's possible to detect and respond to Geolocation permission changes with JS, making the banner redundant.
Is there any way to prevent it? I assume no, it's a deliberate choice by Chrome because it probably will apply to most sites.

I'm not familiar with this new prompt. Is it coming from something the user does, or something the application does? If it's the application, it shouldn't be able to disable user authorization. That would be like bypassing the user authorizing use of the camera or microphone.

@Barmar the user has just authorized the permission in this scenario, and now the browser is telling them the page needs reloading, for that change to take effect.  Only OP is asking if that message can be suppressed, because they can detect this change (and react to it) on the current page, without reload.

@C3roe Even if you can detect the permission change, it sounds like you can't really do anything with it until the reload.

@Barmar - that's exactly the point, you can act on the permission change without a page reload. If you handle that with JS (i.e. update your UI accordingly) then the banner is not very helpful.
